# Using a user's ID after registration with a second query

Tags: php, database, variables, mysqli

I have a registration page created, but I want to send the user's information to another db table I have created. The new added query I am creating is working and sending the info I am wanting to the db, but it is not sending the user_id to my new db table called 'payment_status'.

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly. I am trying to do grab the user_id with a session (but I'm not logged in yet, so I don't know if this is causing it).

Is there a way to ensure my new query is sending after the information goes to my first db table called 'users' and then grab the user_id from the 'users' table and put it in my table 'payment_status'?

In my initial query I am not manually typing in the user's id. It is my primary Auto increment 'id' of my users table.

My initial create query:

```
if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {
                $user->create(array(
                    'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                    'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                $success = "You have successfully created an account. We will notify you once the account has been approved. Then you will be able to login.";
                echo $success;

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                $error;
            }
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

Then my new query:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
$firstname = Input::get('firstname');
$payment_name = "Owes";
$payment_id = 1;
$payment_amount = 0;
}


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

This is the line that is not sending correctly

```
$user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
```

It is showing up as a 0 for anyone I register. This line of code works if I have a user signed in because it grabs the 'id' row from the users table. So the row in the users table I am trying to get is 'id'.

Am I doing this correctly or what can I try?

UPDATE: 
I tried this...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

I commented out my user_id variable that was listed before this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use last insert id

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

// Print auto-generated id
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con); 

mysqli_close($con);
```

From :http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

Comment: How can I add this into my second query though? Would it be just like this  $user_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); ?

Comment: @Becky Put after your insert query 
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); this will return you last insert id

Comment: I updated my question with what I did. I tried putting the variable after my prepare insert. It still returned 0 in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global variable` or `session` or `cookie` to store `last insert id`.
And use `last insert id` after the `$stmt->execute()`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
$user_id = $_SESSION['last'];
$firstname = Input::get('firstname');
$payment_name = "Owes";
$payment_id = 1;
$payment_amount = 0;

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();
$_SESSION['last']=$stmt->insert_id;
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }



}
```

Try this code. You are executing query outside submit request.

Comment: Didn't work. I already started a session and I got a warning, so I removed your session code in the beginning. I'm still getting a 0 value in my user_id field in my payment_status db table.

Comment: echo your query or check the datatypes of `payment_status` table. Is it same as in `bind_param()` ?

Comment: For payment_status I have `id` set as AI and primary as int 11. I have `user_id` as int 11 as well.

Comment: can you please echo your query here ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to echo the query results. I've never done it before. I just searched it, but do not know how I could apply it to my code.

Comment: `INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (, 0, , Owes, 1, 0)`

Comment: here id and firstname is missing. So that may be a reason of your problem. Here i updated my code. I put your query in `if` condition. check it :)

Comment: I changed the code so the if isset closing bracket was after the execute code and it still isn't getting anything. I'm not sure why firstname didn't pull anything. `id` is getting and AI integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82265/discussion-between-milan-kyada-and-becky).